# Запуск ordered test в tfs 2015

Tags: visual-studio, test-automation, tfs, assembly, order

Здравствуйте. Проблема в том, что я могу запустить ordered test только на своей машине (где был создан тест). Как сделать, чтобы он запускался на всех машинах? В TFS 2015 указываю в Test Assembly ***test*.orderedtest. Я только осваиваю тестирование. Спасибо

Comment: Добрый день. К сожалению Вы не очень понятно описали проблему, желательно добавить несколько скриншотов. Какой литературой Вы пользовались для решения проблемы? Попробуйте [ЭТО](https://books.google.ru/books?id=eni-XlPWVysC&pg=PA180&lpg=PA180&dq=tfs%20ordered%20test%20relative%20links&source=bl&ots=TFmbAhZor2&sig=8KRjUeMEM7rDs_xXhWeZ-S1jjV4&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjPsM61s9zMAhUBvSwKHSO_C84Q6AEIJDAB#v=onepage&q=tfs%20ordered%20test%20relative%20links&f=false)
=)

Comment: Скорее всего проблема с абсолютными ссылками, которые генерируются по умолчанию, можно попробовать их отредактировать по типу `<*Directory path="%SystemDrive%\Workspace" includeSubDirectories="true" />`